# Replace everything between [ and ] in regex java

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove everything between `[ ]`.

Example:

**My Input :** `ab[cd]e`

**Expected Output :** `abe`.

---

I tried using `\[` and `\]`, but it is reported as an illegal escape sequence.

Can anyone please help me with this.

P.S.: I am using Java 1.7.

Comment: Show us your code, the regex should work

Answer (score 19):

Use [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String s = "ab[cd]e";
s = s.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", ""); // abe
```

This will replace `[`, `]`, and everything in between with an empty string.

Comment: @SaiSunder: `\\[` matches the left square bracket `[`, `\\]` matches the right square bracket `]`, and `.*?` matches everything between the  square brackets.

Comment: @SaiSunder Mark the answer as accepted (click the check mark below the answer's score) if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Joao Silva: Why do we need `?` sign in this regexp?

Comment: @maks: Because `*` is a greedy quantifier. Thus, if you had the string `ab[cd]e[z]`, using `\\[.*\\]` would result in just `ab` instead of `abe`, because `.*` would match everything up to the final `]`. By using `?`, you make the quantifier reluctant instead of greedy. In other words, each time you consume a character, the regex will *lookahead* and see if the next character is `]`, instead of consuming the entire string and then backtracking.

Answer (score 7):

Try the replaceAll method

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]","")
```